# Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 can't enable module

Tags: php, magento

I'm using not modified Magento ver. 1.7.0.2. 
I installed module [AW blog](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blog-community-edition-by-aheadworks.html) and it's working great, than installed [AW rssreader](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/rss-reader.html) and I can't enable it in `Admin->Configuration->Advanced`

It's making some strange behavior, when I trying to enable it - this module is workin until cache clear(in this time it's still saying Disabled in admin area).

Module is active in config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <AW_Rssreader>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </AW_Rssreader>
    </modules>
</config>
```

There is no errors in exception or system logs, in admin area config saying to be saved

Is there any way to set module as `Enabled` in database?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have enabled compilation for Magento.

Check your system.log to understand the scenario better.

Comment: Thanks for answering:

Compiler Status:
Disabled;
Compilation State:
Compiled.

So I think that compilation is disabled.
The system.log is empty.

Comment: With enabled compilation bug isn't fixed

Comment: set <active>true</active> to <active>false</active>, disable the extension from System > Configuration > Advanced, clear cache and reindex; then set <active>false</active> to <active>true</active>, enable the extension from System > Configuration > Advanced, clear cache and reindex.

I assume compilation is disabled.

Comment: Still not working, thanks for help, but I'l find out another solution - Create my own module based on aw_rssreader functionality.